# How to get only data (exported) fields from protobuf struct with reflect?

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers

My proto file look like this

```
message DeviceOption {
  string ApID = 1;
  string Other = 2;
}
```

After run protoc, the `DeviceOption` struct generated like this:

```
type DeviceOption struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    ApID  string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=ApID,proto3" json:"ApID,omitempty"`
    Other string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=Other,proto3" json:"Other,omitempty"`
}
```

Now, in server I wanna parse all available fields using https://pkg.go.dev/reflect. My code is like:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(pb.DeviceOption{
            ApID: "random1",
            Other: "random2",
        }) 
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    // Do my thing
}
```

`v.NumField()` returns 5, which means it includes all the fields, including **state**, **sizeCache**, **unknownFields** which we don't want. We just want **ApID** and **Other**.

Is there any other way to let reflect return only data (exported) fields, and ignore metadata (unexported) fields?

Comment: How do you define "data fields" and "metadata fields"? I know what you mean in the example, but please formalize it.

Comment: @icza I'm new to protobuf, guessing those fields state, sizeCache, unknownFields are metadata , which protobuf added to serving some control. While data fields in this case , are ApID and Other , which define by us in the .proto file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `NumFields` correctly returns the number of fields either exported or unexported.

#### Go 1.17 and above

Use [`StructField.IsExported`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructField.IsExported)

```
for _, f := range reflect.VisibleFields(v.Type()) {
     if f.IsExported() {
          // do your thing
     }
}
```

#### Up to Go 1.16

To know which ones are exported, check if field `PkgPath` is empty.

One could also use [`CanSet`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.CanSet), but the implementation of `StructField.IsExported` in Go 1.17 is [literally](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/type.go#L1146) `f.PkgPath == ""`.

The documentation on the `PkgPath` field states:

> `PkgPath` is the package path that qualifies a lower case (unexported) field name. It is empty for upper case (exported) field names. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Uniqueness_of_identifiers

```
typ := v.Type()
for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {
    if f := typ.Field(i); f.PkgPath == "" {
         // do your thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely not a good idea to use `reflect` on the struct types generated by the protobuf compiler. Their exact structure should be considered an implementation detail. Some versions of the compiler used to generate exported fields named `XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral`, `XXX_unrecognized` and `XXX_sizecache`, which would have been picked up as "data" fields if you only consider the structure of the Go type. I don't think there's any specific guarantee that might not happen again.

The [google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect) package offers methods to dynamically inspect messages. Given a message `m`, you can do the following to range over all fields set on it:

```golang
proto.MessageReflect(m).Range(
  func (field protoreflect.MessageDescriptor, value protoreflect.Value) bool {
    // return `true` to continue, `false` to break
    ...
  })
```

Or you can use `proto.MessageReflect(m).Descriptor().Fields()` to get an interface representing a list of declared fields in the message.

See also: [A new Go API for Protocol Buffers](https://blog.golang.org/protobuf-apiv2)